# UICollectionViewCell - how to select all items/cells in UIButton action method

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to select all `UICollectionViewCell`s after a `UIButton` is tapped.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated for Swift 3**

Just Shadow's Answer updated to Swift 3

```
  for i in 0..<assetCollectionView.numberOfSections {
    for j in 0..<assetCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: i) {
        assetCollectionView.selectItem(atIndexPath: IndexPath(row: j, section: i), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select all cells in the first section through:

```
for (NSInteger row = 0; row < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]; row++) {
    [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

If you have more than 1 section, just use another nested for loop to loop through all the sections.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [_assetCollectionView numberOfSections]; i++)
{
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [_assetCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:i]; j++)
    {
        [_assetCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i] animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated to Swift 4**

Updated Indrajit Sinh Rayjada's answer and put into an extension, as this is so general that it really should be an extension.

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func selectAll() {
        for section in 0..<self.numberOfSections {
            for item in 0..<self.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                self.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: item, section: section), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
            }
        }
    }
}
```